# How to prove that a given set is strongly invariant?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider a dynamical system

$\dot{x}=f(x)$,

where $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is of class $\mathcal{C}^1$. For any time $t$, denote a solution issuing from $x$ by $X(t,x)$. Consider the proper and definite positive function $V:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ and, $\forall r\in\mathbb{R}$, the set
$$Z( r)=\bigcap_{l\in\mathbb{N}}\{x:V(X(t,x))>r,t>l\}$$
How can I show that,

$$\forall t>0,\quad X(t,Z(r ))=Z( r) \quad ??$$

Comment: Why would you like to know? As formulated, this looks like a homework problem to me.

Comment: Actually it is an exercise that I've been doing.

Answer (score 0):

A set is strongly invariant if it can be written as the union of orbits.

The definition of $Z(r)$, translated to English, is: $Z(r)$ is the union of all orbits along which $V(r)$ is eventually greater than $r$.

---

If the above is not clear, take a more formal approach: a set   is strongly if it has the property that every orbit meeting the set is contained in it. Then observe that if $x\in Z(r)$, then any point on the   orbit passing through $x$ is also in $Z(r)$.